# How to move a view step by step by TranslateAnimation on android

Tags: android, android-animation, translate-animation

I want to move view from (-100, 0) to (-50, 1) to (10, 1) to (100, 2) step by 
step. 
I tried TranslateAnimation. but i failed. 
It only works on the first step, after that is moving not like I set it.

This is my code:

```
x1 = (0-layoutW);
x2 = (45*Constant.metricW-layoutW);
y1 = layoutH;
y2 = ((356-layoutH)*Constant.metricH);
Animation step1 = new TranslateAnimation(
            Animation.ABSOLUTE, x1, Animation.ABSOLUTE, x2,
            Animation.ABSOLUTE, y1, Animation.ABSOLUTE, y2 );
step1.setStartOffset(300);
step1.setDuration(100);
step1.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
animationSet.addAnimation(step1);

x1 = (45*Constant.metricW-layoutW);
x2 = (86*Constant.metricW-layoutW);
y1 = ((356-layoutH)*Constant.metricH);
y2 = ((288-layoutH)*Constant.metricH);
Animation step2 = new TranslateAnimation(x1, x2, y1, y2);       
step2.setStartOffset(400);
step2.setDuration(100);     
step2.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
step2.setFillAfter(true);
animationSet.addAnimation(step2);
```

Did i miss anything? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the set performs all animation at once

You could try with

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html

adding the next step `onAnimationEnd()`